# Convert Bitmap to Pixbuf

Tags: c#, gtk#

i am planing to display my generated bitmap in gtk image.

but it only support Pixbuf.
how to convert  Bitmap in to Pixbuf.

can i use TypeConverter to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done it different way.
other than convert i have reloaded the image.

```
protected void OnBtnGenClicked (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(300, 300);
    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
    {
        Font font = new Font("Arial", 20, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Point);
        g.Clear(Color.White);
        g.DrawString(txtMessage.Text, font, Brushes.Black, 0, 0);
    }
    bmp.Save("d:/image.png", ImageFormat.Png);
    var buffer = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes ("d:/image.png");
    var pixbuf = new Gdk.Pixbuf (buffer);
    image1.Pixbuf = pixbuf;
}
```